# BK Tree implementation

Tags: python, tree, python-3.x, cython

I'm working on a system that can search for similar images. This involves being able to search by edit-distance, and as such I've implemented a special data-structure called a [BK tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BK-tree). Some [notes here](http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees).

The core idea here is to be able to search for items by edit distance, in this case [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) between discrete items. My hashes for this system are stored as 64 bit integers, but fundamentally they can be considered bit-fields, and are treated as such.

In any event, I have some test code that seems to work fairly well, and I'd greatly appreciate some input.

```
from libc.stdint cimport uint64_t

# Compute number of bits that are not common between `a` and `b`.
# return value is a plain integer
cdef uint64_t hamming(uint64_t a, uint64_t b):

    cdef uint64_t x
    cdef int tot

    tot = 0

    x = (a ^ b)
    while x > 0:
        tot += x & 1
        x >>= 1
    return tot

cdef class BkHammingNode(object):

    cdef uint64_t nodeHash
    cdef set nodeData
    cdef dict children

    def __init__(self, nodeHash, nodeData):
        self.nodeData = set((nodeData, ))
        self.children = {}
        self.nodeHash = nodeHash

    # Insert phash `nodeHash` into tree, with the associated data `nodeData`
    cpdef insert(self, uint64_t nodeHash, nodeData):

        # If the current node has the same has as the data we're inserting,
        # add the data to the current node's data set
        if nodeHash == self.nodeHash:
            self.nodeData.add(nodeData)
            return

        # otherwise, calculate the edit distance between the new phash and the current node's hash,
        # and either recursively insert the data, or create a new child node for the phash
        distance = hamming(self.nodeHash, nodeHash)
        if not distance in self.children:
            self.children[distance] = BkHammingNode(nodeHash, nodeData)
        else:
            self.children[distance].insert(nodeHash, nodeData)

    # Remove node with hash `nodeHash` and accompanying data `nodeData` from the tree.
    # Returns list of children that must be re-inserted (or false if no children need to be updated),
    # number of nodes deleted, and number of nodes that were moved as a 3-tuple.
    cpdef remove(self, uint64_t nodeHash, nodeData):
        cdef uint64_t deleted = 0
        cdef uint64_t moved = 0

        # If the node we're on matches the hash we want to delete exactly:
        if nodeHash == self.nodeHash:

            # Remove the node data associated with the hash we want to remove
            self.nodeData.remove(nodeData)

            # If we've emptied out the node of data, return all our children so the parent can
            # graft the children into the tree in the appropriate place
            if not self.nodeData:
                # 1 deleted node, 0 moved nodes, return all children for reinsertion by parent
                # Parent will pop this node, and reinsert all it's children where apropriate
                return list(self), 1, 0

            # node has data remaining, do not do any rebuilding
            return False, 1, 0


        selfDist = hamming(self.nodeHash, nodeHash)

        # Removing is basically searching with a distance of zero, and
        # then doing operations on the search result.
        # As such, scan children where the edit distance between `self.nodeHash` and the target `nodeHash` == 0
        # Rebuild children where needed
        if selfDist in self.children:
            moveChildren, childDeleted, childMoved = self.children[selfDist].remove(nodeHash, nodeData)
            deleted += childDeleted
            moved += childMoved

            # If the child returns children, it means the child no longer contains any unique data, so it
            # needs to be deleted. As such, pop it from the tree, and re-insert all it's children as
            # direct decendents of the current node
            if moveChildren:
                self.children.pop(selfDist)
                for childHash, childData in moveChildren:
                    self.insert(childHash, childData)
                    moved += 1

        return False, deleted, moved

    # Get all child-nodes within an edit distance of `distance` from `baseHash`
    # returns a set containing the data of each matching node, and a integer representing
    # the number of nodes that were touched in the scan.
    # Return value is a 2-tuple
    cpdef getWithinDistance(self, uint64_t baseHash, int distance):
        cdef uint64_t selfDist

        selfDist = hamming(self.nodeHash, baseHash)

        ret = set()

        if selfDist <= distance:
            ret |= set(self.nodeData)

        touched = 1


        for key in self.children.keys():
            if key <= selfDist+distance and key >= selfDist-distance:
                new, tmpTouch = self.children[key].getWithinDistance(baseHash, distance)
                touched += tmpTouch
                ret |= new

        return ret, touched

    def __iter__(self):
        for child in self.children.values():
            for item in child:
                yield item
        for item in self.nodeData:
            yield (self.nodeHash, item)

class BkHammingTree(object):
    root = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = 0

    def insert(self, nodeHash, nodeData):
        if not self.root:
            self.root = BkHammingNode(nodeHash, nodeData)
        else:
            self.root.insert(nodeHash, nodeData)


        self.nodes += 1

    def remove(self, nodeHash, nodeData):
        if not self.root:
            raise ValueError("No tree built to remove from!")

        rootless, deleted, moved = self.root.remove(nodeHash, nodeData)

        # If the node we're deleting is the root node, we need to handle it properly
        # if it is, overwrite the root node with one of the values returned, and then
        # rebuild the entire tree by reinserting all the nodes
        if rootless:
            print("Tree root deleted! Rebuilding...")
            rootHash, rootData = rootless.pop()
            self.root = BkHammingNode(rootHash, rootData)
            for childHash, childData in rootless:
                self.root.insert(childHash, childData)

        self.nodes -= deleted

        return deleted, moved

    def getWithinDistance(self, baseHash, distance):
        if not self.root:
            return set()

        ret, touched = self.root.getWithinDistance(baseHash, distance)
        print("Touched %s tree nodes, or %1.3f%%" % (touched, touched/self.nodes * 100))
        print("Discovered %s match(es)" % len(ret))
        return ret

    def __iter__(self):
        for value in self.root:
            yield value
```

This is written in cythonized Python, for performance reasons (it was *slow* in pure Python). Right now, it's pretty speedy (a 4.1M item tree builds in about 20 seconds), but I have sneaking suspicions I'm missing something, particularly as I still really don't deeply understand metric spaces.

I think the tree is implemented correctly, but it wouldn't surprise me if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party, but this looks like you'd probably be better off just using PyPy to me. It looks like the kind of stuff PyPy is really good at optimizing. I know it's not always possible to use PyPy, though.

Comment: @Veedrac - Interesting. The major issue is that I'm on python 3.4, and need `psycopg2`. I wanted a chance to play with cython anyways.

Comment: It seems you're in luck: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psycopg2cffi. [Their benchmarks](http://chtd.ru/blog/bystraya-rabota-s-postgres-pod-pypy/?lang=en) put it in quite a good light, too. Downgrading to 3.2 should be relatively simple if you don't use `yield from` a ton.

Comment: @Veedrac - To be honest, I'm pretty happy performance-wise at this point. I'm mostly interested in correctness, rather then performance optimizations. I have enough other areas where performance is sufficiently terrible that any further effort here would be somewhat moot.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't really checked for correctness, but here are some general style points.
I haven't taken the time to actually understand the algorithm here; these are
surface-level opinions. If you want deeper analysis of the code correctness, I suggest you give me a testing harness (just something to `pyximport` and run the code), so I get a look at how it's used.

I don't have substantial criticism of the code; it's mostly really neat and readable.

First: docstrings. Instead of:

```
# Compute number of bits that are not common between `a` and `b`.
# return value is a plain integer
cdef uint64_t hamming(uint64_t a, uint64_t b):
```

write

```
cdef uint64_t hamming(uint64_t a, uint64_t b):
    """
    Compute number of bits that are not common between `a` and `b`.
    return value is a plain integer
    """
```

If you're actually targetting 3.4 only, don't write `(object)` in the inheritance list.
If you're potentially wanting 2.x compatibility as well, though, it's good to keep it.

You have

```
    cdef set nodeData
    cdef dict children
```

It's worth noting that these aren't much faster than bog-standard untyped attributes,
but as long as you're aware they are a good datatype. This is actually why I expect
PyPy will give better speed advantages.

Instead of `set((nodeData, ))` just write `self.nodeData = {nodeData}`.

In `remove` you have `cdef uint64_t deleted = 0`, but only add to it once. Giving
this a type is pointless, especially because your return casts it
to a Python type. A similar but lesser concern exists for `moved`.

Instead of `self.children.pop(selfDist)` do `del self.children[selfDist]`. `pop` is
meant for if you use the return value.

You write:

```
        ret = set()

        if selfDist <= distance:
            ret |= set(self.nodeData)
```

It seems to me that

```
        ret = set()

        if selfDist <= distance
            ret = set(self.nodeData)
```

would be better. If not, try `ret.update(self.nodeData)`.

You don't need to call `.keys()` here:

```
        for key in self.children.keys():
```

This:

```
            if key <= selfDist+distance and key >= selfDist-distance:
```

should just be

```
            if selfDist-distance <= key <= selfDist+distance:
```

or even

```
            if abs(key - selfDist) <= distance:
```

I don't know how this would work with `selfDist` being a `uint64_t` and `key` being a Python `int`, but if you just remove the `cdef uint64_t` it'll likely work.

You should probably avoid class variables like `root = None` and just add them to
`__init__`. Class variables are basically global variables,
and although having an immutable global as fallback works, it goes counter to how
I'd expect the language to be used.

Comment: Regarding the points about `set`/`dict`, yeah, I know they're not that great. I was considering trying to use some of the Boost::Set/Boost::Dict classes at one point (cython can interoperate with C++, apparently), but it wound up not being to necessary. I wrote the code with that scaffolding in place for that reason. I may still revisit it for memory efficiency issues at some point.

Comment: The global `root` is intentional, I want to fail noisily if I have multiple instances (there's some threading stuff on top of this that has had it's share of issues).

Comment: I somehow didn't know you could initialize sets as `{stuff}`. Cool!

Comment: There's something subtle going on with the `if key <= selfDist+distance and key >= selfDist-distance:` bit. If I change it to `if abs(key - selfDist) <= distance:`, my unit tests fail. There's some confusing unsigned/signed conversion stuff going on in there.

Comment: The docstrings point is very valid, though. As is the simple overwriting of `ret` with a new set if needed.

Comment: @FakeName wrt. `abs(...) <= distance`, you're mixing `uint`s, Python `int`s and C `int`s in the same line. Of course something would go wrong somewhere! If there are more bugs in the code, that's probably what would cause them XD.

Comment: Yeah, basically, I wrote a test harness, manually figured out what should go where, and fidgeted with things until it worked. Anyways, current file is [here](https://github.com/fake-name/IntraArchiveDeduplicator/blob/master/deduplicator/cyHamDb.pyx), and tests are [here](https://github.com/fake-name/IntraArchiveDeduplicator/blob/master/Tests/Test_BKTree.py) and [here](https://github.com/fake-name/IntraArchiveDeduplicator/blob/master/Tests/Test_BKTree_Issue_1.py)

Comment: If you clone the [whole repo](https://github.com/fake-name/IntraArchiveDeduplicator), you can run the test-harness via the `runTests.sh` file in the repo base (which has a lot of other tests), or manually as `python3 $(which nosetests) --exe Tests.Test_BKTree_Issue_1 Tests.Test_BKTree`. `runTests.sh` will probably be cranky if you don't have a local postgres instance, so running the tests directly is probably a better idea.